# InviewNotifierList (Parent) is getting rebuild when I scroll Child ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm Trying To implement Instagram reels UI but when I scroll the comments list, the Inview Notifier list gets to rebuild and plays the initially provided video in the background and pauses
the current video.

[Github Repo Link](https://github.com/akmalviya03/reels_ui_animation)

I have tried To use automatic keepAlive, also tried with scroll controllers. But nothing is preventing parent list from getting rebuild.

[Video Demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Kea_S9pAi-usvVvrzYw-E56KapyEdyZ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

edit 1, after further inspection, in `videoAnimationTile.dart`

delete initState,
and move all the logic to `didchangedependancies`, like this:

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));

    BetterPlayerConfiguration betterPlayerConfiguration = BetterPlayerConfiguration(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      aspectRatio: (9 / 16),
      //Turned visibility off of icons by setting value to false.
      controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(showControls: false),
    );

    //  Setting Up Data Source
    BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
      widget.url,
      cacheConfiguration: BetterPlayerCacheConfiguration(
          useCache: true,
          //We Had To Change these Settings.
          maxCacheSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
          maxCacheFileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024),
    );

    _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(betterPlayerConfiguration);
    _betterPlayerController.setupDataSource(dataSource);
  }
```

and change your inview to this:

```
  child: InViewNotifierWidget(
   id: widget.url,
   builder: (BuildContext context, bool isInView, Widget child) {
if (isInView) {
_betterPlayerController.setLooping(true);
 _betterPlayerController.play();
   } else {
   _betterPlayerController.pause();
   }
```

This will only loop the video currently in view, this was causing the problem in the first place, it looped everything that was started.

---

Problem solved

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QRx5bqWWk84RjouvtQO7CsEcOOjSohLl/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please let me check.

Comment: Not Working bro

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. We are rebuilding inviewnotifier before the previous build was completed.

Comment: convert your widget to a stateless widget, because you are using a consumer, you won't need it to be stateful, but a new error is progress.

Comment: Same Error. I guess the problem is with the inviewnotifier list. It can't distinguish between parent and child scroll.

Comment: remove notify listeners from the provider `void setLastKnownIndex`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230530/discussion-between-creator-and-huthaifa-muayyad).